# How can I send put request to backend through ejs template without using form?

Tags: jquery, css, node.js, express, ejs

i want to know is there anyway to send a put request to backend on a button click in ejs ?
i my case I want to just send a 'id' to the backend so that through that id i can update my data in database.
also, is it necessary to use form every time to send post/get request to the server in ejs? or is there any other possible way to do so?

code snippet for some idea :

ejs:

```
          <% if(user[i].complaint_type === "Bin Full"){ %>
            
          <form action="/assignCol" method="POST">
            <button
              name="id"
              value="<% user[i].id %>"
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-info"
              style="margin-left: 630px;"
            >
              Assign collector
            </button>
          </form>
```

can I do like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is really common but has a very simple solution, On the frontend side, you have a function `fetch` it is the same as `node-fetch` in NodeJs

With `javascript`, function fetch you can easily request `API` with `[GET, PUT, POST]` and other methods

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
```

you can pass many parameters with `METHOD` or you can simply avoid them

for you this can easily work:

just read values from **form** using javascript function, put it in data `JSON` variable and then use this function

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'PUT',
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
    }
```

Remember this is asynchronous function don't forget to use `await` with it.

For better understanding go to this MDN link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this you will need to use an npm module called "method-override". So first install method-override npm module:

```
npm i method-ovverride
```

Now in your app.js or server.js add the following to configure method-override as a middleware:

```
const methodOverride = require('method-override');


app.use(methodOverride());
```

now you need to mention in your form in ejs that this will take the data to PUT route like this:

```
<form action="/assignCol?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <button
          name="id"
          value="<% user[i].id %>"
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-info"
          style="margin-left: 630px;"
        >
          Assign collector
        </button>
</form>
```